# Overridden function not firing

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I've created a control inheriting from gridview:

```
Partial Public Class nullGridView
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView

    Protected Overrides Function CreateAutoGeneratedColumn(ByVal fieldProperties As AutoGeneratedFieldProperties) As AutoGeneratedField

        ' Create an AutoGeneratedField object. 
        Dim field As New AutoGeneratedField(fieldProperties.DataField)

        ' Set the properties of the AutoGeneratedField using 
        ' the values from the AutoGeneratedFieldProperties  
        ' object contained in the fieldProperties parameter. 
        CType(field, IStateManager).TrackViewState()
        field.HeaderText = fieldProperties.Name
        field.SortExpression = fieldProperties.Name
        field.ReadOnly = fieldProperties.IsReadOnly
        field.DataType = fieldProperties.Type
        field.NullDisplayText = "NULL"

        Return field

    End Function

End Class
```

I can then create instances of the class in codebehind and put them into placeholders.  However, the function I'm trying to override never fires.  I checked its signature against both Microsoft documentation and other sources, and it appears to be identical to the documented signature, but it never gets invoked.  Any suggestions on why it doesn't work, or how to go about debugging this kind of problem?

(Note I also put a constructor into the class, and that got called OK - it is only the above that isn't getting called).

Comment: I just ran across a similar issue after installing VS2013 on new PC with a custom control we have written that has worked for years and this method does not appear to be firing after building using the 2013 compiler (even targeting .NET 4).  This method is marked as obsolete now in .NET 4.5, so not good to use going forward, but haven't found out what (if anything) replaces it yet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.createautogeneratedcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the [GridView.AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) documentation:

> When the AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true, an
>   AutoGeneratedField object is automatically created for each field in
>   the data source. Each field is then displayed as a column in the
>   GridView control in the order that the fields appear in the data
>   source. This option provides a convenient way to display every field
>   in the data source; however, you have limited control of how an
>   automatically generated column field is displayed or behaves.

Are you setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to true somewhere? You'll also need to give the Grid a data source. What kind of datasource are you using?

If you have set up everything according to the link above, you shouldn't have to override the function to get the behavior in your code because it will automatically create those instances. Further, take a look at [the documentation for that function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.createautogeneratedcolumn.aspx): it's obsolete-- so it's difficult for me to know what it does today.

If you look at [the property's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) it gives some options on how you might control what get's generated, like using a `ColumnsGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Yes, AutoGenerateColumns is set to true, and the grid's datasource is set to a Linq Query.  Here's how the gridview is instantiated:  
    `Dim gv = New nullGridView`
    `placeholder.Controls.Add(gv)`
    `gv.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSource1"`
    `gv.AutoGenerateColumns = True`
    `gv.DataBind()`    
The reason I'm overriding the function is so that I can get support for NULL in an arbitrary table.  Is there another way to do that?